# How can I move an object around an Ellipse (In the shape of an Oval)

Tags: java, ellipse

I am a complete beginner in Java and would like to have an object move around the edge of an ellipse continuously. I understand that the formula for this is:

```
x = A * sin(t)
y = B * cos(t)
```

Where A is the x radius, B is the y radius, and t is the time.

My predicament is that I do not understand what methods to implement to use sine and cosine in my code. Also, how can I get the "t" value?

Thanks,

Comment: in java, the Math.sin() and Math.cos() functions take an angle as a parameter in radians.

Comment: The trig functions are in `java.lang.Math`. Time can be got from `System.nanoTime()` or `System.currentTimeMillis()`. If you are using AWT or Swing, `javax.swing.Timer` can call your routine periodically from which you can repaint your component.

Answer (score 0):

Use Java static utils methods:

```
Math.sin(t)
Math.cos(t)
```